# How do I get the base iterator from boost::strided_iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, range

So, I'm finally looking into the range libraries.  Unfortunately, because my work is still using C++14 I'm going to have to use boost (not that boost isn't great, but I just can't use std).

I'm thinking that a natural use for `boost::adaptors::strided`, is to look at flat 2d arrays.  However, seems that I can't get the base iterator.

My code:

```cpp
        auto output = [value](auto& os, auto const& it) -> decltype(auto) {
            return os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
                << (int)it << std::dec;
        };
        for (auto it : value | boost::adaptors::strided(16)) {
            // Where's the base?!?
            auto end_it{ std::min(it.base() + 16, value.end()) - 1};
            for (auto it2 : boost::make_iterator_range(it, end_it)) {
                output(os, *it2) << " ";
            }
            output(os, *end_it) << std::endl;
        }
```

I would assume the original iterator is there somewhere.  How do I get access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Using a ranged-for loop like

```
 for (auto&& el : range)
```

will encapsulate the iterator. `el` is **not** an iterator, but a (reference to) element value.

So, to see the iterator, don't use ranged-for.

Note also that `it.base()` will return the same as `it.base_begin()` so you need to index manually.

Also fixing related issues in the display loop:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using R = std::vector<int>;
    R value = {
        1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, //
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, //
        33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, //
        49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, //
        65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, //
        81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, //
    };

    auto output = [value](auto& os, auto const& it) -> decltype(auto) {
        return os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)it << std::dec;
    };
    auto&& strided = value | boost::adaptors::strided(16);

    std::ostream& os = std::cout;

    for (auto it = std::begin(strided), end = std::end(strided); it != end; ++it) {
        R::iterator //
            b = it.base_begin() + it.get_index(),
            l = std::min(b + 16, value.end()) - 1;

        std::cout << "at " << std::setw(2) << std::distance(value.begin(), b) << ": ";
        for (auto el : boost::make_iterator_range(b, l)) {
            output(os, el) << " ";
        }
        output(os, *l) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b258e2cd3d94b975)**

```
at  0: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10
at 16: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20
at 32: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30
at 48: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 40
at 64: 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50
at 80: 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f 60
```

Comment: `std::min(b + 16, value.end()) - 1` is potentially UB, you probably want `(std::distance(b, value.end()) >= 16) ? b + 16 : value.end()`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed. I was going to comment on the error prone details, but really thought it more useful to show how I'd write it using better tools:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3072b51fd05b6add We have to spend time wisely :)